# Hosting a static Sapper site in a subfolder in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, svelte, sapper

I have a page that uses `fetch` in `onMount`, that I export using `sapper export`, then upload to Google Cloud Storage to be hosted as a static site...

when a page is requested with a trailing `/` everything works great but when it is requested without a trailing `/` GCS redirects to `/index.html`... when this happens the `fetch` doesn't run... it looks like a 2nd `index.[hash].js` file that contains the `fetch` isn't being requested. All the styles load & routing works fine.

I'm not worried about GCS redirecting to `/index.html`, that's expected... what I'm wondering is if svelte/sapper is able to run normally if `index.html` is in the url?

[EDIT]
**Important info: I'm hosting the site under a subfolder**! Hosting it at the root works perfectly, like [joshnuss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/306520/joshnuss) mentions below.

Before exporting, I updated `src/server.js` to this:

```
polka()
  .use(
    "/test1", //<----- THIS IS THE SUBFOLDER
    compression({ threshold: 0 }),
    sirv("static", { dev }),
    sapper.middleware()
  )
  .listen(PORT, err => {
    if (err) console.log("error", err);
  });
```

I export the site with the following command:

```
yarn run sapper export --legacy --basepath="/test1"
```

Comment: Tried it locally on a fresh sapper install, and the `onMount` runs no matter if trailing slash is passed or not.

Comment: I left an important piece of info out: I'm hosting the site under a subfolder... I updated the question

Comment: Try setting the `basepath` option:, see more here: https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#Base_URLs

Comment: I export the site with `yarn run sapper export --legacy --basepath="/test1"`